# Is there any chance of `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` erasing data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgraphile, savepoints

### Question

When working with SQL, I am familiar with preparing SQL statements, and then either committing them if nothing goes wrong, or bailing out if something does (which to my understanding leaves the database unchanged).

I am now however in a position where I think I need to use `SAVEPOINT` instead (using postgraphile/postgreSQL - see context below). However, if you run:

```
await someSqlClient("SAVEPOINT blah");

try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  await someSqlClient("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT blah");
  ...
} finally {
  await someSqlClient("RELEASE SAVEPOINT blah");
}
```

...Does that run the risk of erasing any other SQL which might have been done at the same time? e.g. maybe this query takes 5 seconds, and in the meantime, say either a few other connections hit my API and each change the database in some way, or maybe I run another query on this same API connection which also changes the database.

I'm not hugely experienced in SQL so I might be misunderstanding something here. e.g. possibly connections might be isolated from each other, and rolling back to a savepoint doesn't deleted any data committed in any other queries/on other API connections?

### Context

I am using Postgraphile (which itself uses PostGreSQL) to construct a GraphQL endpoint, and am using savepoints similar to here https://postgraphile.org/postgraphile/current/make-extend-schema-plugin#mutation-example. My resolver needs to run some more GraphQL inside (as is done here https://postgraphile.org/postgraphile/current/usage-schema#calling-a-resolver-from-a-resolver), which, by my understanding, commits the resulting sql i.e. you have no option to "prepare" a statement in GraphQL. I therefore need to use savepoints, like in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry. The savepoint concerns only data from your own session and your own transaction. If you `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`, all that happened *in your current transaction* since the savepoint was set will be undone.

The documentation does not spell that out in that level of detail, I guess because the authors assume that it is evident that a savepoint is part of your transaction. It is evident as soon as you understand that savepoints are implemented as *subtransactions* of your current transaction.

See the [documentation of the internals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/subxacts.html) for some implementation details.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe It is not subtransaction, but partial transaction because a sub transaction would be totally inside the main transaction ]...[ while a partial rollback (TO SAVEPOINT) has its begining ref to the start point of the main transaction... PostGreSQL is not able to do subtransaction...

Comment: @SQLpro It is a subtransaction, which is totally inside the main transaction. See `src/backend/access/transam/README` in the source for details.

Comment: Some guy even wrote an article about sub transactions: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/subtransactions-and-performance-in-postgresql/

Comment: @Frank_Heikens the concept of subtransaction is a transaction inside another transaction not a partial transaction of the initial transaction  that SAVEPOINT do... This is an error of language... From  ACM https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/782034.782038 "A nested transaction is a hierarchy of subtransactions, where each subtransaction may contain other subtransactions, or contain the atomic database operations read and write"

Comment: @SQLpro You have a point in that "subtransaction" is not a well-defined term. The SQL standard does not define it. When I speak of a subtransaction in the context of PostgreSQL, I am talking about subtransactions as defined in PostgreSQL. You or random authors of an academic paper are free to define the term in some other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LaurenzAlbe! One more question, I guess it follows that I can use the same `SAVEPOINT` name on all my separate transactions with no chance of conflicts? i.e. I only might have to think about changing it if I used two savepoints in the same transaction

Comment: Try it and see :^)

Comment: @Laurenz Albe, Unfortunately, it is the tragedy of PostGreSQL that it does not use academic terms and those used by professionals, which introduces confusion... For example "planer" for optimizer, "cluster" for instance, "attribute" for column, "relation" for table, "bloating" for fragmentation, "spacename" for SQL schemas, "index-only scan" for seek, "block" for page... What Chris Date (Tedd's Codd  collaborator who created Relational DBMS) ) denounces in his book "SQL and the Relational Theory". Yes, you are free to say whatever you want!

Comment: @SQLpro There I go again, discussing with you... but this is my last comment. You imply that the people writing PostgreSQL are not professionals, which exposes itself as the unwarranted slander that it is. Don't assume that the terms you prefer are necessarily better. Perhaps read a second book about databases for a change.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe says "*You have a point in that "subtransaction" is not a well-defined term. The SQL standard does not define it.*" Contrary to what you say, the SQL standard has perfectly defined the thing. See my answer below. The definition of SAVEPOINT is: *An SQL-transaction may be partially rolled back by using a savepoint*

Answer (score 0):

Due to the inappropriate terminology of PostGreSQL which does not follow the SQL language standard, the term "subtransaction" should not be understood in the sense of subtransaction, but of partial transaction as noted in the SQL standard ISO/IEC 9075-2 (foundation) of which here is a copy of the extract.

[image: SAVEPOINT as defined in the ISO SQL standard]

This means that it is possible to cancel the end of a transaction by going back to any point in time referenced by a SAVEPOINT, but the transaction will always start at the moment of the START TRANSACTION (or BEGIN TRANSACTION, both commands being admitted ) and not as one might think, a cancellation of part of the transaction, for example between two SAVEPOINTs....